How to invoke method when parameter is a generic
We have a huge list with implementation instances of a generic interface. Then we get an element of any type. With some filter logic we find the correct instance out of the list.
How can we invoke a method and pass the element?
interface Processor<T> {
  fun process(element: T)
  // [many more methods ...]
}

// ***** implementations *****
class StringProcessor : Processor<String> {
  override fun process(element: String) {}
}

class IntProcessor : Processor<Int> {
  override fun process(element: Int) {}
}
// 50+ implementations for different types

// ***** invocation logic *****
fun main() {
  val allProcessors = listOf(StringProcessor(), IntProcessor()) // dynamically loaded

  val elementToProcess = "Test"
  val correctProcessor = allProcessors
    .first { /* logic that element type matches processor type */ true }
  
  correctProcessor.process(elementToProcess) // <-- how to invoke this method??
}

The only (really bad) solution we found was using reflection:
fun main() {
  val allProcessors = listOf(StringProcessor(), IntProcessor()) // dynamically loaded

  val elementToProcess = "Test"
  val correctProcessor = allProcessors
    .first { /* logic that element type matches processor type */ true }
  
  // bad idea ... but works
  val method = correctProcessor::class.java.getMethod("process", Any::class.java)
  method.invoke(correctProcessor, elementToProcess)
}

How is it possible to invoke the method without reflection?

what is your "logic that element type matches processor type" like?

The problem is that you are trying to select an instance of a class depending on the run-time type of a parameter, and that's tricky. You could create a map of class to processor instance and inline functions that implicitly take and use the class of the given parameter:

inline fun <reified T: Any> pairClassTo(processor: Processor<T>) =
    T::class to processor

val processors = mapOf<KClass<*>, Processor<*>>(
    pairClassTo(StringProcessor()),
    pairClassTo(IntProcessor())
)

@Suppress("unchecked_cast")
inline fun <reified T : Any> process(element: T, klass: KClass<out T> = element::class) {
    val correctProcessor = processors.getValue(klass) as Processor<T>
    correctProcessor.process(element)
}

fun main() {
    val elementToProcess: Any = "test"
    process(elementToProcess) // uses StringProcessor
}

